# Using GeoFire with Apps Script

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, geofire

I'm looking to store latitude and longitude information on firebase using GeoFire. The latitude and longitude info is located in a google spreadsheet. Are there any scripts like [this one](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/source) to do this? If not, how would I be able to send geolocation information from my apps script?

Comment: Did you do any research? Some relevant hits with "google spreadsheet to firebase".

Comment: Yes, and I am successfully able to write data to firebase from my spreadsheets. To be clear, I am now looking to write the lat/long info stored in the spreadsheet as a GeoFire object in firebase.

Comment: Take a look at GecCode Class in Maps [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/geocoder).  It's pretty easy to use.

Comment: You might want to take a look at these [limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits).